# Mercurial/.hgignore - How do I ignore everything but the contents of a folder?

Tags: regex, file, directory, mercurial, hgignore

I have a NetBeans project and the Mercurial repository is in the project root. I would like it to ignore everything except the contents of the "src" and "test" folders, and .hgignore itself.

I'm not familiar with regular expressions and can't come up with one that will do that.

The ones I tried:

(?!src/.*)

(?!test/.*)

(?!^.hgignore)

(?!src/.*|test/.*|.hgignore)

These seem to ignore everything, I can't figure out why.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
syntax: regexp

^(?!src|test|\.hgignore)
```

This is basically your last attempt, but:

- It's rooted at the beginning of the string with `^`, and
- It doesn't require a trailing slash for the directory names.

The second point is important since, as [the manual](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) says:

> For example, say we have an untracked file, file.c, at a/b/file.c inside our repository. Mercurial will ignore file.c if any pattern in .hgignore matches a/b/file.c, a/b or a.

So your pattern must *not* match `src`.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! That really helped, it works like a charm now, and I see where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?!src\b|test\b|\.hgignore$).*$
```

should work. It matches any string that does not start with the word `src` or `test`, or consists entirely of `.hgignore`.

It uses a word boundary anchor `\b` to ensure that files like `testtube.txt` or `srcontrol.txt` aren't accidentally matched. However, it will "misfire" on files like `src.txt` where there is a word boundary other than before the slash.

Comment: How can this be changed so that only certain subdirectories are not ignored? e.g. app/design/frontend/rc